# Using Azure AD token in AJAX call from MVC application to separate WebAPI application

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, azure, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I have created a Azure AD protected .Net Core 2.0 WebAPI that has its own URL, and using same clientID, tenantID and domain I am able to send AJAX call from a SPA using ADAL JS.

Now, I need to implement the same without the use of ADAL JS in a MVC application. The issue I am facing is that the token generated by OIDC is not getting authorized on the separate API app.

Any suggestions for this scenario?

Comment: If you can provide some code that you are using, it will be helpful to find the problem.

Comment: On a high level what you should be doing is: a) If your MVC app handles authentication with OIDC, you should use the authorization code to get the access token b) Or if your JavaScript calls the MVC app which then calls the API, you can use the On-Behalf-Of grant to get the access token, e.g. https://joonasw.net/view/azure-ad-on-behalf-of-aspnet-core

Comment: Hey Joonas, I used your earlier post while creating the AD auth for the WebAPI. Will check this one out. Thanks